# WooCommerce add class name in the list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently, I am trying to customise the override WooCommerce.php file. Now, in this file,

```
<section id="content woocommerce" class="grid-block woocommerce">
<ul id="products" class="subcategory-products products">
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
</ul>
</section>
```

The output likes:

```
<li class="post-15 product type-product status-publish hentry first instock">
    <a href="http://shop.bbpixelz.dk/product/i-phone-ai-template/">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="http://shop.bbpixelz.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/iphone-ai-template-150x150.png" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="iphone-ai-template">
        <h3>I-Phone Vector Template</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">$2</span></span>
    </a>
    <a href="/?add-to-cart=15" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="15" data-product_sku="ai-iphone" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a>
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is to change the class name, currently the class name is `post-15 product ...`. I would like to change the class name to product category.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 12):

Please refer [overriding templates via a theme](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) first.

There is a file called content-product.php in woocommerce templates folder.

find `<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>> ......... </li>`

that classes you have generated by `$classes` . you can add your new class to it. just add following code to right before the `<li>` tag. here is it.
 `<?php $classes[] = 'your-new-class' ?>;`

PS. dont edit your plugin template files directly. Create new folder called woocommerce in your theme directory and copy woocommerce template files to that folder. and then edit files.